# Android home button press area

Tags: android

I have this strange issue with the press area for the android up button i am setting the home as up like this

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and i have 2 Samsung Galaxy Nexus on one of the devices the home button clickable area includes both the icon and the text. While on the other device only the icon is included in the clickable area? why is this? how can i get the text and the icon to always be included in the clickable area?

Note on the tablet i have the home button clickable area is both the text and the icon.

Answer (score 0):

In order to cover both cases, you might just need to add the following into your menu selection to be sure that it is covered.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Manually go up with a call.
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't change anything. one of the devices is 4.3 and the other is 4.2 but the 4.3 is my personal device and when it was 4.2 i remember the whole area being clickable so i don't think that is the problem

Comment: Ah, I had an issue with something similar recently forcing me to use setIndicatorBoundsRelative in 4.3 instead of setIndicatorBounds in 4.2.  It forced me to basically use reflection to take care of the problem. It could be something similar here.